# How to get a compiler warning when an IBOutlet is disconnected

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, compiler-warnings, xib, iboutlet

How can I have Xcode warn me if an IBOutlet of one of my objects is not hooked up to anything in a NIB?

I can check that outlets are connected at runtime by adding `assert(ofEveryOutlet);` in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad`. But it's not as useful, or reliable, as having the compiler do the checking for me.

Comment: In Xcode 4.2, there's now a dot in the margin next to an IBOutlet that indicate if it's connected or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (compiled) NIB files are loaded and connected at runtime, so I don't think there is a way for the compiler to check this. I think your best bet is the asserts you've already suggested...

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a Unit Test target that checks your IB bindings and make your application depend on it. That way it will get checked each time you build. See http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/03/testing/testing-view-controllers for an example of this approach

Comment: That has the nice property of failing earlier at compile time. Unfortunately it's (generally) a bit more work than assert(), and I *still* have to remember to update the unit tests when I add an IBOutlet. So in my estimation it's a wash